# recursive gitignore for all files with pattern

Tags: git

I want to ignore all files with the pattern `d*.cpp`. These file could be in the same directory as .gitignore, or in any sub-directory.

How should that rule look like?
`**/d*.cpp` does not do what I think it should.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't added or committed some of the files previously?

Comment: `git status` lists for example `src/mod/dd_file.cpp` as Untracked file (with the rule in place), so it should not be previously committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `**` syntax is not available for .gitignore in early versions of git. The solution is to upgrade to 1.8.2.1 or later.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern looks correct. `git` will ignore any `d*.cpp` file anywhere in your git repository. However; gitignore works only for untracked files; as written in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> gitignore - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore

If you want to ignore changes to the `d*.cpp` files that have already been added to your repository; you can use `--skip-worktree` or `--assume-unchanged`. You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/2082964) for a good explanation of these two concepts. (special thanks to @1615903 for pointing me to skip-worktree)

Comment: `--skip-worktree` is more appropriate, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/1615903